# I have 3 sets of wires going to an outlet. I would like to add another outlet from this one, how do i do it?

Tags: electrical

I am trying to add another outlet to this one but i'm a little confused as there are 3 sets of wires going to this one outlet that i want to daisy chain from.  How could i add another outlet from this one?.

Comment: Post a picture of what you have.  If it's complicated, draw a diagram.

Comment: FYI if you have a receptacle where both screws and backstabs are in-use, that is not allowed.   There are ways to fix that.    Other than that, this is a bit complicated, and it depends an awful lot if any of the sockets are switched by a switch,   Switched receptacles are very common, and tee-branching wiring at a receptacle is less common, so we need to know which.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that all electrical boxes are restricted on the numbers of wires they are allowed to hold based on their basic volume.  (Over-crowding in the box is considered inherently unsafe.) That being said, for the new outlet, simply add the new cable into the box. Tie all the blacks together under one wire nut. And under this nut as well include one free length of black wire the same gauge about 10" long.  Ensure the wire nut is tight and all the conductors are captured. Push this wire nut to the back of the box.  Do the same with the whites and grounds. Reinstall the original outlet.

Comment: I am concerned the third cable might be for a switch loop for one of the sockets.

Comment: Is the tab broken on the side of the receptacle?